# How do I recreate the rotating minus button that Apple uses in the standard iOS UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface, core-animation

I want to recreate the rotating minus button that Apple uses in it's UITableViews when in edit mode. You can see the animation in [this video on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFxtZEW7Dis#t=290s).

Is there a way to embed this button (and animation) into my own view somewhere else? Or do I actually have to recreate it? Would I need images for each state?

In addition, here is a picture of the button mid-animation from that video.

[image: Button Animation]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a button and using the shadow properties of the `layer` attribute won't work because when the image rotates, you don't want the shadow to also rotate. I recreated this effect by doing the following. I created two images that were 35px square. Once called `delete-icon-bg.png` and one called `delete-icon-dash.png`. `delete-icon-bg.png` is just the red circle style like I want it, and the `delete-icon-dash.png` is a transparent png with a white dash centered where I want it over the background. Then I configure the button like so:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delete-icon-bg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delete-icon-dash.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(didTouchDeleteButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
button.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

The method `didTouchDeleteButton:` then looks like this:

```
- (void)didTouchDeleteButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (sender.selected) {
        sender.selected = NO;
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"undoRotateDash" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        sender.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    } else {
        sender.selected = YES;
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotateDash" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        sender.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a little reminder: if you used the imageEdgeInsets, you probably need to set a new imageEdgeInsets. Don't worry about the animation.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do this with just a single image:

[image: Table Delete Button]

but you would need to create a custom animation to do the rotation from horizontal to vertical.  The animation seems pretty easy though, <s>you could probably just change the `imageOrientation` property of the [`UIImage`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) from `UIImageOrientationUp` to `UIImageOrientationLeft`</s>.

`image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.571);` will rotate the image 90 degrees.

As mentioned in the comments, the shadow may look weird doing it this way so I suggest finding an image with no shadow and then using the `UIImage` `layer` property to rotate the `shadowRadius`, `shadowOffset`, etc.

[`UIImage` Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
[`CALayer` Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500)

Comment: Hm, how would I go about adding the different states during the rotation? Otherwise the shadow would rotate as well.

Comment: How about you have the shadow be a separate image than the red circle, under the red circle

Comment: What @kris said sounds like a good idea.  Trim the button image to have no shadow, then use [`CALayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500) `shadowRadius`, `shadowOffset`, etc.